# calculating hourly average based on condition of the other column in r

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a data frame which has 3 columns
first:(date_time) every 10 minutes one observation,
second: temp,
third:  quality check(those that are not acceptable=NA)

I want to calculate hourly average and I want to say that for every hour that has more than 2 na in Quality check column (in the six observations that are in one hour ) the corresponding average should be NA. how can I do that I wrote this code but I don't know how can I consider the condition of Quality column  :

```
df %>% 
   mutate(date = date(date_time), hour = hour(date_time))  %>%
   group_by(date, hour) %>%
   summarise(m = mean(temp))
```

Comment: I don't know how to that .. and I have no time .. sorry .. but I tried to explane every thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use an `if/else` condition

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date_time), hour = hour(date_time)) %>%
    group_by(date, hour) %>%
    summarise(m = if(sum(is.na(quality)) > 2) NA_real_ 
               else mean(temp, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: thank you very much .. It should be right ..I can not understand the meaning of "  NA_real_" ?

Comment: @Faranakomidi it is not make sure that the `NA` used is the correct type i.e. `mean` returns a double value.  By ddefault, `NA` is `NA_logical_` which may have some type issue in certain cases when there is no coersion to class